# How to get elements from parent document?

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe

I have a window called win1, which spawns an iframe called iframe1.
Iframe1 spawns another iframe called iframe2.
How can i access an element of win1 ? If i have to get the parent of iframe2, i will do this :

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('ID').style.display="none";
```

What shall i do if i want to have an element id of the win1 from iframe2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window.top in the iframe2 to access object of the very top window.
Alternativelly, you could access:

```
window.    parent.    parent
(iframe2)  (iframe1)  (top window)
```

Comment: It may be usefull to know that expression `window.top==window` is used to detect whether window is in iframe or not.